# How to put and get IBM MQ messages without application server

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I'm a newbie in IBM MQ (https://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/products/cloud-integration/mq-trial/index.html)

I'd like to know if I could send and get messages from IBM MQ using some code like this:

```
/* 
 * Sample program 
 * © COPYRIGHT International Business Machines Corp. 2009
 * All Rights Reserved * Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
 *
 * This sample program is provided AS IS and may be used, executed,
 * copied and modified without royalty payment by customer
 *
 * (a) for its own instruction and study,
 * (b) in order to develop applications designed to run with an IBM
 *     WebSphere product for the customer's own internal use.
 */

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import com.ibm.websphere.sib.api.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.websphere.sib.api.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.websphere.sib.api.jms.JmsQueue;
import com.ibm.websphere.sib.api.jms.JmsTopic;

/**
 * Sample code to programmatically create a connection to a bus and
 * send a text message.
 * 
 * Example command lines:
 *   SIBusSender topic://my/topic?topicSpace=Default.Topic.Space MyBus localhost:7276
 *   SIBusSender queue://myQueue MyBus localhost:7286:BootstrapSecureMessaging InboundSecureMessaging 
 */

public class SIBusSender {

  /**
   * @param args DEST_URL,BUS_NAME,PROVIDER_ENDPOINTS,[TRANSPORT_CHAIN]
   */

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, IOException {


// Parse the arguments
if (args.length < 3) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      "Usage: SIBusSender <DEST_URL> <BUS_NAME> <PROVIDER_ENDPOINTS> [TARGET_TRANSPORT_CHAIN]");
}    
String destUrl = args[0];
String busName = args[1];
String providerEndpoints = args[2];    
String targetTransportChain = "InboundBasicMessaging";
if (args.length >= 4) targetTransportChain = args[3];

// Obtain the factory factory
JmsFactoryFactory jmsFact = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance();

// Create a JMS destination
Destination dest;
if (destUrl.startsWith("topic://")) {
  JmsTopic topic = jmsFact.createTopic(destUrl);
  // Setter methods could be called here to configure the topic
  dest = topic ;
}
else {
  JmsQueue queue = jmsFact.createQueue(destUrl);
  // Setter methods could be called here to configure the queue
  dest = queue;
}

// Create a unified JMS connection factory
JmsConnectionFactory connFact = jmsFact.createConnectionFactory();

// Configure the connection factory
connFact.setBusName(busName);
connFact.setProviderEndpoints(providerEndpoints);
connFact.setTargetTransportChain(targetTransportChain);

// Create the connection
Connection conn = connFact.createConnection();

Session session = null;
MessageProducer producer = null;
try {

  // Create a session
  session = conn.createSession(false, // Not transactional 
                               Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

  // Create a message producer
  producer = session.createProducer(dest);

  // Loop reading lines of text from the console to send
  System.out.println("Ready to send to " + dest + " on bus " + busName);
  BufferedReader lineInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));      
  String line = lineInput.readLine();
  while (line != null && line.length() > 0) {

    // Create a text message containing the line
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
    message.setText(line);

    // Send the message
    producer.send(message,
                  Message.DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE,
                  Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY,
                  Message.DEFAULT_TIME_TO_LIVE);        

    // Read the next line
    line = lineInput.readLine();
  }

}
// Finally block to ensure we close our JMS objects 
finally {

  // Close the message producer
  try {
    if (producer != null) producer.close();
  }
  catch (JMSException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to close message producer: " + e);
  }

  // Close the session
  try {
    if (session != null) session.close();
  }
  catch (JMSException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to close session: " + e);
  }

  // Close the connection
  try {
    conn.close();
  }
  catch (JMSException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to close connection: " + e);
      }

    }
  }

}
```

I created the queue in the IBM MQ Explorer.

My main doubt is how to do the connection and go on without application server.

Comment: My system uses wildfly 11. Your suggestion can be about using wildfly.

Comment: Strange question. First you ask how to use IBM MQ without an app-server, then you say you have an app server (Wildfly) while the code you show are not in fact IBM MQ related, but the IBM SI BUS JMS provider - specific to the IBM WebSphere Application Server. Anyhow, the official docs of IBM MQ take you through the process in detail. Have you even checked it out? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031950_.htm